# Kafka - performance test

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka version: 0.9

Command:

```
 kafka-run-class org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance –-topic testY --num-records 10000 --record-size 5000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=servers --throughput 10
```

**Error:**

> usage: producer-performance [-h] --topic TOPIC --num-records
>   NUM-RECORDS --record-size RECORD-SIZE --throughput THROUGHPUT
>   --producer-props PROP-NAME=PROP-VALUE [PROP-NAME=PROP-VALUE ...] producer-performance: error: unrecognized arguments:  '–-topic  testY 
>   --num-records  10000  --record-size  5000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=servers --throughput 10'

What is wrong with the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an oversized dash before topic.

```
kafka-run-class org.apache.kafka.tools.ProducerPerformance --topic testY --num-records 10000 --record-size 5000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=servers --throughput 10
```

Comment: I din't know how it happened. In my console, all looks similar. I deleted and typed again. it is working.